# linear-gradient(...) in CSS3 not working according to specifications?

Tags: html, css

Here's the current version of my webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>my site</title>


    <style type="text/css">
        #mtx_bckgd
        {
            font-family: Courier New;
            height: 1000px;
            width: 1000px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        #mtx_bckgd > p
        {
            word-wrap: break-word;
            color: #D8D8D8;     
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #header
        {
            position: absolute;
            font-family: Trebuchet MS;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 70px;
            text-align: center;
            border: solid 2px #424242;
            top: 25px;
            font-size: 20;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change_bckgd()
        {
            var bitstr = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < 4000; ++i)
                bitstr += Math.floor(Math.random()*10) % 2 ? "0" : "1";
            document.getElementById("mtx_txt").innerHTML = bitstr;

        }
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="mtx_bckgd">
        <p id="mtx_txt"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>JaminWEB</h1>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(change_bckgd, 200);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I plan on doing is creating a vertical fade across the background, from white at the bottom to light grey (the same grey I used for the 0's and 1's in the background) at the top.

According to W3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp), the syntax

```
background: linear-gradient(angle, color-stop1, color-stop2);
```

means I should add the line

```
background: linear-gradient(90, white, #D8D8D8)
```

in the #mtx_bckgd block in the stylesheet. But when I do that, I'm getting a dark blue fade and my 0's and 1's are turning white.

Comment: FYI, you're font dec is incorrect: `font-family: Trebuchet MS;` - can't have spaces in font names without wrapping in quotes, like so: `font-family: "Trebuchet MS";`

Comment: Also FYI, W3Schools is not a good resource.  I'd recommend reading this article instead: [CSS3 Gradient Background](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/)

Comment: The problem is the `90` you have in there. Take that out, and it will work. Or change it to `90deg`.

Comment: @cale_b W3Schools usually has good info, people just misread it sometimes. I'd be reluctant to say it's a bad resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the "90" in `background: linear-gradient(90, white, #D8D8D8)` is incorrect. According to W3Schools it should be:

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, white, #D8D8D8)
```

or

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, white, #D8D8D8);
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/muPGL/1/)